# What does "rake routes" actually do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

In a fresh(ish) rails project, the `Rakefile` looks like this:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Blog::Application.load_tasks
```

Yet `rake routes` produces the following output:

```
cpe-74-72-73-47:rails-blog-example djechlin$ rake routes
home_index GET /home/index(.:format) home#index
      root     /                     home#index
```

I don't understand how `rake` works so that it can get to the routes file or the routes task. Per the [command line usage](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/doc/command_line_usage.rdoc) documentation, `rake` is invoked as

```
rake [options ...]  [VAR=VALUE ...]  [targets ...]
```

But the page has no explanation of what the targets are. I assume `rake` is called directly on the `routes.rb` file from this and that `Rakefile` is not related, but I can't confirm this at all.

Answer (score 7):

A Rakefile contains executable Ruby code. Anything legal in a ruby script is allowed in a Rakefile.

When you trigger `rake routes` [you call this piece of Ruby code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake#L2) .

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the Rakefile is very related, and rake isn't called directly on routes.rb at all. Rake needs a rakefile. The magic happens inside `load_tasks`, which load the numerious Rails-specific Rake tasks that come with the framework.

When you invoke Rake, it looks for a Rakefile. The Rakefile is just Ruby. In your default Rakefile, first it includes `../config/application`, where your application class (`Blog::Application`) is defined; then it invokes `load_tasks`, which is provided by `Rails::Application`, from which your `Blog::Application` inherits.

From there there are a million ways for each part of Rails to make Rake tasks available. Typically the core libraries provide Rail ties which expose tasks.

Comment: `rake routes` first runs the `Rakefile`, which calls `AppName::Application::load_tasks`, which creates a task called `:routes`, which is then executed since it was passed as argument to `rake`. Right?